# PPTP VPN won't reconnect after faluire

Tags: networking, server, vpn, pptpd

I configured a PPTP vpn in /etc/network/interfaces this way:

```
auto tunnel
iface tunnel inet ppp
    provider server1
```

The link is correctly broken up on boot or when I issue `ifup tunnel`, but when it fails it won't automatically restart, I need to bring it up manually!
This is what I found in the logs:

```
pppd[857]: No response to 4 echo-requests
pppd[857]: Serial link appears to be disconnected.
pppd[857]: Connect time 1742.1 minutes.
pppd[857]: Sent 82272 bytes, received 17223 bytes.
pppd[857]: MPPE disabled
pppd[857]: Connection terminated.
pppd[857]: Modem hangup
pptp[833]: anon warn[decaps_hdlc:pptp_gre.c:204]: short read (-1): Input/output error
pptp[833]: anon warn[decaps_hdlc:pptp_gre.c:216]: pppd may have shutdown, see pppd log
pptp[842]: anon log[callmgr_main:pptp_callmgr.c:234]: Closing connection (unhandled)
pptp[842]: anon log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:251]: Sent control packet type is 12 'Call-Clear-Request'
pptp[842]: anon log[call_callback:pptp_callmgr.c:79]: Closing connection (call state)
pppd[857]: Exit.
```

Am I missing an option in order to have it automatically reconnect, or is that just not implemented, and I must check VPN status via cron?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the 'persist' option in the peer configuration file. Adding it solved my issue